# Navigate through all the search results pages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can not seem to grasp.
How can I make BeautifulSoup parse every page by navigating using Next page link up until the last page and stop parsing when there is no "Next page" found. On a site like this

[enter link description here](https://www.avito.ru/moskva/transport)

I try looking for the Next button element name, I use 'find' to find it, but do not know how to make it recurring to do iterations until all pages are scraped.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

beautiful soup will only give you the tools, how to go about navigating pages is something you need to work out in a flow diagram sense.

Taking the page you mentioned, clicking through a few of the pages it seems that when we are on page 1, nothing is shown in the url.

```
htt...ru/moskva/transport
```

and we see in the source of the page:

```
<div class="pagination-pages clearfix">
   <span class="pagination-page pagination-page_current">1</span>
   <a class="pagination-page" href="/moskva/transport?p=2">2</a>
```

lets check what happens when we go to page 2

```
ht...ru/moskva/transport?p=2

<div class="pagination-pages clearfix">
  <a class="pagination-page" href="/moskva/transport">1</a>
  <span class="pagination-page pagination-page_current">2</span>
  <a class="pagination-page" href="/moskva/transport?p=3">3</a>
```

perfect, now we have the layout. one more thing to know before we make our beautiful soup. what happenes when we go to a page past the last available page. which at the time of this writing was: 40161

```
ht...ru/moskva/transport?p=40161
we change this to:
ht...ru/moskva/transport?p=40162
```

the page seems to go back to page 1 automatically. great!

so now we have everything we need to make our soup loop.

instead of clicking next each time, just make a url statement. you know the elements required.

```
url = ht...ru/moskva/$searchterm?p=$pagenum
```

im assuming transport is the search term??? i dont know, i cant read russian. but you get the idea. construct the url. then do a requests call

```
request =  requests.get(url)
mysoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text)
```

and now you can wrap that whole thing in a while loop, and each time **except the first time** check

```
mysoup.select['.pagination-page_current'][0].text == 1
```

this says, each time we get the page, find the currently selected page by using the class pagination-page_current, it returns an array so we select the first element [0] get its text .text and see if it equals 1.

this should only be true in two cases. the first page you run, and the last. so you can use this to start and stop the script, or however you want.

this should be everything you need to do this properly. :)

Comment: Basically, I've discovered that there is a pattern in url for these pages; That is s={pagecount}. Increments go by 120; First page does not have a s= variable at all. How do I add s= to a default first page of search results url, and then will increment by 120 every next page? And how do I make Python IF: if there is no particular data on page, means that we passed the last page of the search results and need to halt?;

Comment: i dont know about the s=120*page variable? when i click next page on your link it says $defaulturl?p=2, then p=3 etc...  but if for you it shows s=120, then 240 etc... i suppose you can incriment pagenum by 120 and continue. as to how to deal with the first page when you construct the url simply add the caviate, `page = ""` then at the end of the for loop or while loop dictate the next page will be page 2 `page=<<logic to detemine page string>>` and after this check to see if we have gone back to the first page again. if we have, then thats a sign to stop.

Comment: I have a variable "tag" - that I have a list of my links in tags = soup.find_all('a'

Comment: I am taking a page, finding urls: soup.find_all('a', class_='result; on one given page and then I need to navigate to the next up until the end. and each page it's supposed to do urls scraping

Comment: so in each while loop you construct the url for the next page. page 1 is done with no page reference. page 2 incorperates ?p=2 and so on and so forth, each time you make a requests call and parse that into beautiful soup. scrape your data, and update for the following page. continue until you detect that you have reached page1 again by using the pagination links i showed in the answer. that should be more than enough to complete this scraping task.

Comment: well, all you have to do is construct the url as a string. use the loop to construct the correct string to pass to requests and use that result in beautiful soup. If this still eludes you i think you might need a better grasp on python and programming logic?

Comment: could you give me a hint on constructing the right string that would iterate with increments of value required? I retrieved the part of the url that is correspondent to page number. how do I incorporate it into mysoup.select['.pagination-page_current'][0].text == 1 that you've explained earlier?

Comment: you dont need anything to construct the string, you already know everything you need to know, inside your loop you just make `urlstring = 'ht...ru/moskva/' + str(searchterm) + str(pagevarstring) + str(nextpagenumber)` each time you go through the loop you just add 1 to pagenumber `pagenumer = pagenuumber+1` and check if page number is 1 to not put it into the url `if pagenumber == 1:  pagevarstring = ''` otherwise `pagevarstring = '?p='  nextpagenumber = pagenumber`    this way when the pagenumber ==1 none of the page url vars are set, but when it is not one, nextpagenumber gets set

Comment: Shall I put it after 'url =', and before operations on the page?

Comment: Your code logic flow needs to work as thus:
1.) create all startup variables  
2.) enter a loop where the condition of exit is that you have reached page 1 a **second** time.  
2.1) inside the loop construct the url for the page we are about to scrape  
2.2) submit the url to requests to get that specific page  
2.3) get all of the data we want off the page  
2.4) grab any relevant data from the page (like the pagination class) that will tell us if we need to exit the loop

Comment: Here's what I am coming up with:

Comment: remainder = "&transport"

page = '?s=120'

urlstring = 'https://avito.ru/search/?' + str(page) + str(remainder)

pagenumber = str(page)+120

print(urlstring)                      But I can't figure how to add increments, it says that you can not add integer, you have to add string... (pagenumber line)

Comment: ok so to get strings and ints working you need to learn how to manipulate variables in python. strings like "10" can be made into integers by using int("10") which will turn them into numbers instead of strings. then you can add things to them like `mynum = "0"` `mynumplusone=int(mynum)+1` then make it a string again by doing `backtostringnow = str(mynumplusone)`. but real talk, i think this project is too big if you are just learning python for the first time, or really any programming language. you need to start with something that has smaller steps to understand these nuances of it.

Comment: in fact just today i pointed another person to a resource i find really good for beginners, and the author is so generous he allows people to read it for free on his website! https://automatetheboringstuff.com/ this is a great book and will help you understand the basics of this kind of logic, plus bonus! it gets to web scraping specifically in chapter 11. everything before that will give you the foundation you need to eventually do this project in a matter of weeks, or even days if you're a fast learner.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup by itself does not load pages. You need to use something like `requests`, scrape the URL you want to follow, load it and pass its content to another BS4 soup.

```
import requests

# Scrape your url
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') # You can now scrape the new page
```

Comment: True that. But I need Python to extract pages on it is own, not me putting the urls into the program

Comment: @AleksandrAnisimov go to your initial page, use BS to extract the link to the next page, load the next page, rinse, repeat.