# Python Using Selenium to scrape data from multiple links on a page

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

My problem is I have a page with multiple user profiles (20 on a page, 50 pages) and I want to use selenium to automate clicking each profile then use maybe beautifulsoup to get the data and store it into a dataframe. Then I want to do that for the next 50 pages. I have just looked into Scrapy which might be better but if there is a solution using Selenium lmk! Thanks in advance

Here is my Code:

```
for i in range(2): 
  actions = ActionChains(browser)
  actions.move_to_element(arrow).click(arrow)
  actions.perform()
  time.sleep(10)
  print(1)

  member_name = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='list-title member-name']/a[1]")
  format(member_name)
  print(3)
```

The format(member_name) is just a function that formats the output

Comment: Follow up thanks for the tip on trying out crawling. Now I have a problem with Action Chains. I try to make a for loop where the action chain clicks on an arrow that supposedly leads to another list of profiles which i then want to scrape with the for loop. I tried using the URL suffix technique however, it loads to the original page and does not load to the next page of profiles. The arrow click is more like scroll after it is clicked but I do not know how to get the new page to come up.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the site and how the paging of results works (implementation specific) e.g. if you can click on the n page of results and the URL suffix then shows some kind of query to show number of results and start from 21 etc. then you don't need Selenium at all you can just do that with a loop and some wait times so you don't spam the site.

There's some useful heuristics on this question's answer which I found useful.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102555/9217153

I'm still not sure I see a clear question, you just describe a problem and propose a solution but I don't see where you get hung up / technical issues / things not working.

There's plenty of guides online as well if you look for them

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3
- https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/

Here's a Youtube video showing how to do it with Scrapy but the same concept applies, it's the URL suffix not the clicking on the pages that matters.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quMUjys9BcU

Here's one showing how page traversal works for Selenium + Python

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjo9yFHoUl8

Comment: Ok thanks i will check these out then get back to u